# Rails 3.2.8 - How do I get the week number from Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know how to get the current week number from Rails and how do I manipulate it:

1. Translate the week number into date.
2. Make an interval based on week number.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "interval"? An interval is the distance between two dates. You can't make an interval from an integer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

> `%U` - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Sunday.  (00..53)
>   `%W` - Week number of the year.  The week starts with Monday.  (00..53)

```
Time.now.strftime("%U").to_i # 43

# Or...

Date.today.strftime("%U").to_i # 43
```

If you want to *add* 43 weeks (or days,years,minutes, etc...) to a date, you can use [`43.weeks`](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Numeric/Time.html#M000324), provided by ActiveSupport:

```
irb(main):001:0> 43.weeks
=> 301 days

irb(main):002:0> Date.today + 43.weeks
=> Thu, 22 Aug 2013

irb(main):003:0> Date.today + 10.days
=> Sun, 04 Nov 2012

irb(main):004:0> Date.today + 1.years # or 1.year
=> Fri, 25 Oct 2013

irb(main):005:0> Date.today + 5.months
=> Mon, 25 Mar 2013
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me clarify the interval. If I have OCT-12 to OCT-19, they belongs to different weeks. I think I can convert each of them to each of their respective week number and then have the week number interval. That's what I meant.

Comment: That's just subtraction. Converting each date to their week number will yield two integers. You can simply subtract the second from the first.

Comment: Note that %V in strftime will give you the week number defined in ISO-8601.

Answer (score 38):

You are going to want to stay away from `strftime("%U")` and `"%W"`.

**Instead, use `Date.cweek`.**

The problem is, if you ever want to take a week number and convert it to a date, `strftime` won't give you a value that you can pass back to `Date.commercial`.

`Date.commercial` expects a range of values that are 1 based.
`Date.strftime("%U|%W")` returns a value that is 0 based. You would think you could just +1 it and it would be fine. The problem will hit you at the end of a year when there are 53 weeks. (Like what just happened...)

For example, let's look at the end of Dec 2015 and the results from your two options for getting a week number:

```
Date.parse("2015-12-31").strftime("%W") = 52
Date.parse("2015-12-31").cweek = 53
```

Now, let's look at converting that week number to a date...

```
Date.commercial(2015, 52, 1) = Mon, 21 Dec 2015
Date.commercial(2015, 53, 1) = Mon, 28 Dec 2015
```

If you blindly just +1 the value you pass to `Date.commercial`, you'll end up with an invalid date in other situations:

For example, December 2014:

```
Date.commercial(2014, 53, 1) = ArgumentError: invalid date
```

If you ever have to convert that week number back to a date, the only surefire way is to use `Date.cweek`.

Answer (score 5):

```
date.commercial([cwyear=-4712[, cweek=1[, cwday=1[, start=Date::ITALY]]]]) → date
Creates a date object denoting the given week date.

The week and the day of week should be a negative 
or a positive number (as a relative week/day from the end of year/week when negative). 
They should not be zero.
```

For the interval

```
require 'date'

  def week_dates( week_num )
    year = Time.now.year
    week_start = Date.commercial( year, week_num, 1 )
    week_end = Date.commercial( year, week_num, 7 )
    week_start.strftime( "%m/%d/%y" ) + ' - ' + week_end.strftime("%m/%d/%y" )
  end

  puts week_dates(22)
```

> EG: Input (Week Number): 22
>
> Output: 06/12/08 - 06/19/08

credit: Siep Korteling http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/125140

Answer (score 3):

[`Date#cweek`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cweek) seems to get the ISO-8601 week number (a Monday-based week) like `%V` in strftime (mentioned by @Robban in a comment).

For example, the Monday and the Sunday of the week I'm writing this:

```
[ Date.new(2015, 7, 13), Date.new(2015, 7, 19) ].map { |date|
  date.strftime("U: %U - W: %W - V: %V - cweek: #{date.cweek}")
}

# => ["U: 28 - W: 28 - V: 29 - cweek: 29", "U: 29 - W: 28 - V: 29 - cweek: 29"]
```