# Ruby on Rails group_by_week

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouping

I am trying to create a request where I group my elements by week. Something like :

```
<%= line_chart @goals.map { |goal|
{name: goal.name, data: goal.feats.group_by_week(:created_at).count}
} %>
```

I am using mysql db so i guess 'trunc('week', element)' does not work for me.

I have also tried to work with the 'groupdate gem', but since I dont work with 'utc' it also gave me an error.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Could you consider adding a new column which is a Date not DateTime and group by that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the timezone of `Groupdate`?

```
Groupdate.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

[see the docs](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#time-zones)

Comment: I get this  Error :::

Comment: Groupdate::Error: ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone must be :utc to use Groupdate

Answer (score 0):

Try play with this:

```
by_week = goal.feats.group_by {|feat| feat.created_at.strftime('%W')}
```

This returns an hash grouped by week, where each key is the week number (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075656/5239030)).

Then you can count how many values per keys:

```
by_week.map {|_k , v| v.length }
```

Which returns an array of counts